# What localhost exactly domains name resolution to ip?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, network-programming

My timing database influx sets the listening port 8088 to address 127.0.0.1, and the spring boot listens to the same port 8088 to any addresses, as shown below.

```
~ lsof -nP -i:8088
   COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   influxd   420  zyx    3u  IPv4 0xf4af94bc970b15e9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8088 (LISTEN)
   java    34029  zyx  171u  IPv6 0xf4af94bc9a0d12e9      0t0  TCP *:8088 (LISTEN)
```

When I try to access spring boot restful using url `localhost:8088/api`, I get the right result. But when I use url `127.0.0.1:8088/api`, I get error `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`.I guess it is caused by mapping to influd instead of spring boot.

But why `localhost` can get the right result? As far as I konw, localhost will resolve to `127.0.0.1`.

I run my program on Mac 2019.

```
~ nslookup localhost
Server:       192.168.15.1
Address:   192.168.15.1#53

Name:  localhost.cluster.peidan.me
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: _"But when I use url 127.0.0.1:8080/api"_ Did you mean 8088? Because if it actually is 8080, it is simply the wrong port. Also mind IPv4 and IPv6. localhost probably resolves to the IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is 8088. I have edited it. You mean localhost probably resolves to the IPv6. So do you have any idea how to confirm it is resolved to the IPv6？